# How could we do unit test of a function which uses DOM?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

***Hello and thank you for your time reading my question!***

I would like to ask, because I am starting with unit testing in Javascript, and I am using Jasmine/Karma.

I am trying to test a function:

```
    export function setRenderer() {
    threeD = document.getElementById('container');
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        alpha: true,
    });
    renderer.setSize(threeD.clientWidth, threeD.clientHeight);
    let blueColor = 0x607d8b;
    let alpha = 1;
    renderer.setClearColor(blueColor, alpha);
    threeD.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}
```

The previous function is being loaded into the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>AMI - Lesson 04</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://use.edgefonts.net/source-code-pro.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dataarts/dat.gui/master/build/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/stats.js/master/build/stats.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.min.js"></script>

    <!-- AMI -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ami.js/0.0.22/ami.min.js"></script>
    ##
</head>

<body>
<div id="my-gui-container">
</div>
<div id="my-lut-container">
    <div>CT
        <div id="my-lut-canvases-l0" class="my-lut-canvases"></div>
    </div>
    <div>Segmentation
        <div id="my-lut-canvases-l1" class="my-lut-canvases"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>

<script src="stats.js"></script>
<script src="loader.js"></script>
<script src="handleSeries.js"></script>
<script src="scene.js"></script>
<script src="gui.js"></script>
<script src="dicomDataUrl.js"></script>
<script src="controls.js"></script>
<script src="camera.js"></script>
<script src="renderer.js"></script>
<script src="animator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js"></script>

<!-- google analytics -->

</body>

</html>
```

Which uses a div to manipulate it creating a renderer.

Also, because of it could really help here I post the k*arma.conf.js*:

```
const packageJSON = require('./package.json');

('use strict');

process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath()

module.exports = function (karma) {
    karma.set({
        // frameworks to use
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'sinon'],

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.16.0/polyfill.min.js',
            `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/${packageJSON.config.threeVersion}/three.js`,
            // ,
            // 'src/core/*.spec.js',
            //'specs/**/*.spec.js',
            'mySpecs/**/*.spec.js',
            {pattern: 'data/**/*', included: false, watched: false, served: true}
        ],

        reporters: ['spec'],

        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {
            'mySpecs/**/*.spec.js': ['webpack']
            //'specs/**/*.spec.js': ['webpack']
            // 'src/core/*.spec.js': ['browserify']
        },

        browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],

        // web server port
        // port: 9876,
        // colors: true,
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: karma.LOG_WARN,

        autoWatch: false,
        singleRun: true,
        colors: true,

        webpack: {
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.js$/,
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        exclude: [/node_modules/, 'external/**/*']
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        webpackMiddleware: {
            // webpack-dev-middleware configuration
            // i. e.
            stats: 'errors-only'
        }
    });
};
```

I have tried the following:

```
    /* globals describe, it, expect, beforeEach*/

import {setRenderer} from '../../lessons/04/renderer'

describe('Configuration', () => {
    it('should true be true', () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
describe('Renderer', () => {
    it('should be created', () => {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.id = 'container';
        document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

        setRenderer();

        expect(document.getElementById('container').toBe(newDiv);
    });
});
```

The first test is because of I am checking if Karma and Jasmine are well configured, and they are, because it passes.

The point is that the tests output:

```
 Configuration
    V should true be true

  Renderer
    × should be created
        ReferenceError: threeD is not defined
            at setRenderer (mySpecs/lesson04/test.spec.js:101:12)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (mySpecs/lesson04/test.spec.js:88:90)


    HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.033 secs / 0.011 secs)
    TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 1 SUCCESS


    1) should be created
         Renderer
         ReferenceError: threeD is not defined
        at setRenderer (mySpecs/lesson04/test.spec.js:101:12)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (mySpecs/lesson04/test.spec.js:88:90)


    error Command failed with exit code 1.
    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I thought it was because of the expectation was failing, however it looks like **the cause is different**, because of if I change the expectation for a trivial true.toBe.false, the output is:

```
    HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.034 secs / 0.013 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 1 SUCCESS


1) should be created
     Renderer
     ReferenceError: threeD is not defined
    at setRenderer (mySpecs/lesson04/test.spec.js:101:12)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (mySpecs/lesson04/test.spec.js:88:90)


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

*I am trying to learn how to do unit testing because I think is a good way to programm, however I do not know how to continue with this example.*

Here is the test in the repo: https://github.com/AtlasULPGC/AtlasULPGC.github.io/blob/master/mySpecs/lesson04/test.spec.js

Renderer function:
https://github.com/AtlasULPGC/AtlasULPGC.github.io/blob/master/lessons/04/renderer.js

The index.html
https://github.com/AtlasULPGC/AtlasULPGC.github.io/blob/master/lessons/04/index.html

Thank you for taking time reading the question!